# nuget “-Allversions” is invalid

Tags: nuget

I am migrating all packages from **nuget. Server** to **Baget** and I have a problem:
I used the `nuget list` command in the migration. But I found that the `-allversions` parameter does not list all package versions.
what should I do, my Baget server only has the latest package. How can I migrate all versions of all packages?
I use version of 5.1 `nuget cli`

Comment: **nuget -allversions** (NuGet Version: 6.1.0.106) does not show all the versions of the package. There are a lot of discussions on the [Nuget Issues](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8130) page. This happens even if you specify the `-Source` to a local folder. BaGet supports package versions pushed by `nuget.exe push`

Do you see the versions of the package (when you select the package name) on BaGet web interface after you migrated from NuGet.Server?

Comment: I did the migration using the 'powershell' command

Comment: Could it be that the [powershell script](https://loic-sharma.github.io/BaGet/import/nugetserver/) is using `nuget.exe list -AllVersions -Source $source` which possibly does not appear to list all assembly version of the nupkgs on your `NuGet.Server`. Do you have directory access to the `packages` directory of your `NuGet.Server`?